# Need advice making a self-watering moss pole for plant

Tags: irrigation, pole, moss

Wasn't quiet sure where to post this, but I am helping my wife make a Moss pole for her plants. The purpose of the moss pole is so that the roots of the climbing plants attach to it and grow bigger (I think). Typically what I've seen is people either misting the moss pole to get it soaked, or using a wicking system which many have said it does not work well.

My idea is to use a 1/2" PVC pipe, use an end cap and drill holes up the PVC, and then wrap the moss around that. Then fill the top of the PVC with water to then get then moss pole saturated. The issue I am facing is I cannot get an even distribution of water.

Different things I've tried:

- I used the smallest drill bit 1/16 and stepped up in size as I went up the pvc, this was a no go as the water pressure was too much at the smallest hole and would cause the bottom of the moss pole to be soaked and not allow the water reach the top of the pvc.
- Tried 3m temflex 1755 which is a cotton coated tape, I used the tape for the bottom half of the pvc holes and it did slow down the pressure, but not enough to get the moss pole evenly wet.

Picture of my failed attempt:

[image]

I tried drawing the problem I am currently facing
[image]

The same problem occurs where the holes are getting larger as they go up, or if they are all the same.
It's possible I am overthinking this, but if anyone has some advice on how I can get an even distribution of water from top to bottom I'd appreciate it.

Comment: you cannot store water in the pipe if you drill holes in it ... the water only needs to exit at the top ... gravity will soak the moss all way down ... a small water pump would work to irrigate the top of the post

Comment: What about creating a wick in the pipe? A strip of cloth or multiple strips, sure the bottom would end up the dampest after a day but when you pour the water in the top would be dampest.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about horticulture, not home improvement.

Comment: Water just doesn't do like that.

Answer (score 1):

Your holes are way too big. Dry your PVC pipe and cover the holes with vinyl electrical tape. Then get the smallest sewing needle you can find and just prick the surface of the tape so you get a slow drip. You can increase the drip rate as you go up the pole by making just a slightly larger puncture. Remember, you want drips, not streams.

Answer (score 0):

I have been thinking about this and I came to the conclusion that a small water pump on a periodic timer will be the most effective solution.

Wicks will work...up to a certain extent. I believe there is a hard limit on how high capillary action will wick up the water unless there is some sort of action forcing some of the moisture up to the very top....like the combo of the little tubes inside vascular plants and the evapotranspiration of the leaves.

Without that sort of combo, the very top will always be a lot drier than the very bottom.

Another solution I came up with is to essentially create little compartments on the pole so that instead of one long pole with one bottom, you have several poles with bottoms. I have done this via using saran wrap to create little packets right on top of the other. The downside to this is that you have to water every packet separately from top to bottom. [image: pole]

Comment: I should add that another solution I am currently using is to simply use a humidifier as a sort of poor man's mister. I used pvc pipes to make it so that the outlet is right on top of my moss poles, effectively creating a poor man's living moss pole. I refill the humidifier every three days or so.